# How to read params object[] items passed from C# in Javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript, silverlight

I am doing a simple program in Silverlight to inkove javascript function in silverlight.

The silverlight function is as under

```
void InvokeJS(params object[] items)
{
object result = System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("JSFunction", items);
}
```

Pasing value to this function is happening as under

```
  InvokeJS((object)new object[]{ (object)"10", (object)"20"})
```

And the JS function is as under

```
function JSFunction(params) {
            alert(params);
        }
```

Now how to read the params value in javascript?

Comment: `var forsureanobject = (object)(object)(object)(object)(new Object());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `params` variable is just the first of many arguments being passed in.  You can access the other arguments using the following syntax:

```
alert(this.arguments[0]);
alert(this.arguments[1]);
alert(this.arguments[2]);
```

If you're passing all the arguments in a single variable, it will be an array so use:

```
alert(params[0]);
alert(params[1]);
alert(params[2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

To the called function, the params array is just that, an array.

In this case you will have an array that looks like this:

```
[ [ "10", "20" ] ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it

```
alert(params[0]); alert(params[1]);
```